# Deactivate masonry animation

Tags: javascript, html, masonry

I've developed a web page using masonry in order to rearrange a set of items of different heights, when user scroll down a "Loading..." message is shown and new items are loaded and layout is recalculated by masonry, so far so good. The problem is that the new items fly from the top left corner of the screen to their new position in the layout and I would like to deactivate that effect, I would prefer to fade in for example better than fly in from the top, or even do not have animation at all, just display the new item in their positions directly.

I am using masonry 3.1.5

I've tried with

```
 $('#container').masonry().masonry( 'transitionDuration', 0 );
 $('#container').masonry().masonry( 'isAnimated', false );
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution that worked for me was:

```
$("#container").masonry({
    transitionDuration: 0
});
```